# Attach a body onload event with JS

Tags: javascript, html, events, onload

How do I attach a body onload event with JS in a cross browser way? As simple as this?

```
  document.body.onload = function(){
      alert("LOADED!");
  }
```

Comment: Why not just use what you're already doing in your example? It works for me

Answer (score 22, accepted):

This takes advantage of DOMContentLoaded - which fires before onload - but allows you to stick in all your unobtrusiveness...

[window.onload - Dean Edwards](http://dean.edwards.name/weblog/2005/09/busted/) - The blog post talks more about it - and here is the complete code copied from the comments of that same blog.

```
// Dean Edwards/Matthias Miller/John Resig

function init() {
  // quit if this function has already been called
  if (arguments.callee.done) return;

  // flag this function so we don't do the same thing twice
  arguments.callee.done = true;

  // kill the timer
  if (_timer) clearInterval(_timer);

  // do stuff
};

/* for Mozilla/Opera9 */
if (document.addEventListener) {
  document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", init, false);
}

/* for Internet Explorer */
/*@cc_on @*/
/*@if (@_win32)
  document.write("<script id=__ie_onload defer src=javascript:void(0)><\/script>");
  var script = document.getElementById("__ie_onload");
  script.onreadystatechange = function() {
    if (this.readyState == "complete") {
      init(); // call the onload handler
    }
  };
/*@end @*/

/* for Safari */
if (/WebKit/i.test(navigator.userAgent)) { // sniff
  var _timer = setInterval(function() {
    if (/loaded|complete/.test(document.readyState)) {
      init(); // call the onload handler
    }
  }, 10);
}

/* for other browsers */
window.onload = init;
```

Answer (score 25):

Why not use `window`'s own `onload` event ?

```
window.onload = function () {
      alert("LOADED!");
}
```

If I'm not mistaken, that is compatible across all browsers.

Comment: window.onload happens after /everything/ is loaded, including images, etc. If you want to start manipulating the DOM as soon as possible to prevent start-up lag, you can't use window.onload.

Answer (score 15):

Cross browser window.load event

```
function load(){}

window[ addEventListener ? 'addEventListener' : 'attachEvent' ]( addEventListener ? 'load' : 'onload', load )
```

Answer (score 9):

`document.body.onload` is a cross-browser, but a legacy mechanism that only allows a single callback (you cannot assign multiple functions to it).

The closest "standard" alternative, [`addEventListener`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/element.addEventListener) is not supported by Internet Explorer (it uses `attachEvent`), so you will likely want to use a library (jQuery, MooTools, prototype.js, etc.) to abstract the cross-browser ugliness for you.

Comment: Internet Explorer supports `addEventListener` [as of version 9](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/ff975245(v=vs.85).aspx).

Answer (score 2):

jcalfee314's idea worked for me - I had a `window.onload = onLoad` which meant that the functions in `<body onload="...">` were not being called (which I don't have control over).

This fixed it:

```
oldOnLoad = window.onload
window.onload = onLoad;

function onLoad()
{
oldOnLoad();
...
}
```

Edit: Firefox didn't like `oldOnLoad = document.body.onload;`, so replaced with `oldOnLoad = window.onload`.

Comment: As Rusky noted on Andreas's answer, window.onload is different from document.body.onload; it happens after everything is loaded, rather than just the DOM.

Comment: Since Firefox at least as far back as version 10 does support oldOnLoad = document.body.onload, I'm using a variation of this: if (oldOnLoad = document.body.onload) { document.body.onload = onLoad; } else { oldOnLoad = window.onload; window.onload = onLoad; }. This seems to give me what I want with most browsers, with the window.onload option as a fallback when needed.

Answer (score -4):

Why not using jQuery?

```
$(document).ready(function(){}))
```

As far as I know, this is the perfect solution.

Comment: This fires before the full document is loaded.