# Body onload function in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html, css, onload

I have the code that I have posted below in my webpage. As you can see it uses the **body onload** function to launch the script. Is there any way of making this script work without this and in JavaScript instead?

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>

<script type="text/javascript">
function box(query){
return document.getElementById(query)
}
</script>

</head>
<body onload="box('query').focus();">

<input id="query" type="text">

</body>
</html>
```

Thanks in advance,
Callum

Comment: Since the onLoad function is provided by JavaScript, you have already solved your problem.

Comment: what are you trying to achieve actually

Comment: You're already using JavaScript. And how would you do something onload if not on the onload event? Your question makes no sense in it's current form.

Comment: i just cant understand y do u want to do that but if u dislike the onload function you can use document.ready function of jquery but again,it makes no sense to avoid onload in the first place

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This might what you're looking for: [Attach a body onload event with JS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1235985/attach-a-body-onload-event-with-js)

I'd suggest using jQuery or some other JavaScript framework unless you're exploring JS or have some stringent restrictions on using libraries and frameworks.

Answer (score 0):

```
the following code helpful for you
this is jquery:

$(document).ready(function(){
              function name();
});

or

$(window).load(function(){
function name();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
the following answers using javascript:
<html>
<head>
    <title>Test</title>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
    <script type="text/javascript">
    function load() {
        alert('function loaded');
    }
    window.onload = load;
    </script>
</head>
<body>
</body>
</html


----------

<html>
<head>
    <title>Test</title>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
    <script type="text/javascript">
    function load() {
        alert('function loaded');
    }
     </script>
</head>
<body onload="load();">

</body>
</html
```

Answer (score -1):

if you are talking about catching the onload event with writting any javascript in your html you can use this function:

```
// Add event
var addEvent = function (obj, evType, fn){
        if (obj.addEventListener){
                obj.addEventListener(evType, fn, false);
                return true;
        }else if (obj.attachEvent){
                var r = obj.attachEvent("on"+evType, fn);
                return r;
        } else {
                return false;
        }
};
```

Now you can run all the functions you need in your onload event.

```
addEvent(window,'load',function () {
   box('query').focus();
   // or
   document.getElementById('query').focus();
});
```