# Body Onload Event

Tags: javascript, dom-events

This code doesn't seem to work:

```
document.body.onload = function () { ... }
```

I know there is a `onload` event for the body tag in html, but how come you can't access it from JavaScript? Is `window.onload` same as `<body onload="...`

It basically never triggers.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1235985/attach-a-body-onload-event-with-js

Comment: I know it should work, and I know how set events handlers, but is there a reason it never triggers?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

1. There is no `body.onload`. When you attach the event in the HTML code, it actually attaches to `window.onload`. So that's the one you should use.
2. It only fires when all the resources (images, scripts, css files, etc.) have fully loaded.
3. If there is another script which also tries to attach to the event (and almost all javascript frameworks do, like jQuery, ExtJS, etc.), then you might get a conflict there. Better attach to the event through the framework;
4. How do you attach it? Maybe you attach the event handler too late, when the page is already loaded.