# How do I check when the HTML component of the DOM has loaded without using a JavaScript library?

Tags: javascript, dom, dom-events

I want to detect when the `<body>` element finishes loading into the DOM from an external script without using an external JavaScript library. I do not want to use `document.ready` or `window.onload` because they do not fire until the entire DOM (including all external files) finishes loading.

Comment: See this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1235985/attach-a-body-onload-event-with-js

Comment: After `</body>` the only element is `</html>`...

Comment: `window.document.body.onload = appendST1();` calls the function immediately. Remove the `()` if you want `appendST1` to be called when the onload event fires.

Comment: Since you've determined that jQuery.ready() will do what you want you could read the source to that function.

Comment: @Mrchief: I already checked that post. It doesn't apply here because the `window.onload` handler will not fire until the DOM has finished loading all external files. (See [this Mozilla developer page](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/window.onload) for details.)

Comment: @ThiefMaster: Removing the () like you recommended didn't work. `window.document.body.onload = appendST1;` still fired before the HTML finished loading into the DOM

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a simple solution that works in ALL browsers:

1. Insert the following code above the `</body>` tag in the HTML:

   ```
   <script type="text/javascript">
     try {
       ONLOAD()
     } catch(e) {
       ONLOADq=1
     }
   </script>

   MINIFIED:
   <script type="text/javascript">try{ONLOAD()}catch(e){ONLOADq=1}</script>
   ```
2. Insert this code in the external javascript:

   ```
   if ( typeof ONLOADq === 'number') {
     ONLOAD()
   };
   ```
3. Place all the code in the external javscript that needs to be run on the page's load into a function called `ONLOAD`.  For example:

   ```
   function ONLOAD() { document.body.appendChild(ST1) };
   ```

The first part covers instances when the external javascript finishes loading before the HTML, and the second part, vice-versa.

Answer (score 0):

For modern browsers use

```
window.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
    // dom is ready
}, false);
```

For IE8 use

```
window.onload = function() {
    // dom is ready
};
```

Comment: @lovesh IE9. IE<9 requires using window onload

Comment: @Raynos: `window.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', ...` will work as I need it to, but `window.onload` will not. `window.onload` is similar to `document.ready`.  It will not fire until all external files have finished loading into the DOM. (See [this Mozilla developer page](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/window.onload) for details.)

Comment: @AlienRober what that means is that its impossible to bind to dom ready for older browsers. jQuery binds to window.onload for legacy browsers

Comment: That's not true. jQuery uses 3 different fallbacks for IE, namely `window.onload`, `document.onreadystatechange`, and the cunning [`doScroll()` hack](http://javascript.nwbox.com/IEContentLoaded/)

Answer (score 0):

why dont you put the script **right above the closing body tag**

```
<body>
..
....

....
<script type="text/javascript".....
</script>
</body>
```

this makes sure that everything has been loaded

*in response to the comment*

put this code in the head of the document

For IE8 and older IEs

```
window.onload= function() {
var script=document.createElement("script");
script.src=url;            // here use the url of the script
document.body.appendChild(script);
};
```

for others

```
window.attachEventListener("DOMContentLoaded",function() {
    var script=document.createElement("script");
    script.src=url;            // here use the url of the script
    document.body.appendChild(script);
    },false);
```

Comment: I know--but I'm developing the page for another user and trying to keep source HTML as clean as possible.  It's actually part of a larger script, and referencing a single external file that can be cached will speed up performance a bit, too.

Comment: the `window.onload` will not fire until all external files have loaded into the DOM. (See [this Mozilla developer page](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/window.onload) for details.)

To be fair, I think I've found a solution, but I can't post it yet (dern lack of reputation points).  I can @comment you when I post it.