# document.body.onload in Firefox

Tags: javascript, firefox

Okay so I'm using Javascript to set the `onload` attribute of a page.  It works in IE but not Firefox.  Does anyone know a fix for this? Neither IE or Firefox is throwing an error. I'm using the Firefox plugin "Web Developer" and it isn't showing any JavaScript errors.  Code below:  Thanks.

```
document.body.onload = setRedirect;
function setRedirect()
{
    alert("TEST");
}
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1235985/attach-a-body-onload-event-with-js

Comment: You can also put this code at the very end of the page.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Change to:

```
window.onload = setRedirect;
```

Also see this [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/scessor/m3DAH/).