# Phonegap deviceready vs document ready

Tags: javascript, cordova

I am experiencing issues with the phonegap device ready event. I am testing under iOS 6.0.

When device ready is fired, the DOM isn't ready. If I bind events to some DOM Elements in a `deviceready`event listener, I will receive no notifications because these elements do not exist at this early time.

So what are the best practices for waiting until BOTH have finished loading - DOM and phonegap?

Comment: Are you doing it like this: 
`document.addEventListener("deviceready", onDeviceReady, false);

function onDeviceReady() {
    // Now safe to use the PhoneGap API
}`
With your reference to 'phonegap....js' before this script.

Comment: deviceready event is meant to fire only after DOMContentLoaded has fired and a message from native code has also been passed to the javascript.

Comment: I found the perfect answer here:

http://stackoverflow.com/a/14109006/1367154

Answer (score 3, accepted):

if your are using jquery try this

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    document.addEventListener("deviceready",onDeviceReady,false);       
});

function onDeviceReady(){
    //write your function body here

}
```

if your are using javascript only try this

```
if(document.readyState === "complete") {
  document.addEventListener("deviceready",onDeviceReady,false); 
}

function onDeviceReady(){
        //write your function body here

    }
```

Answer (score 1):

try something like this:

```
function onLoad(){
  document.addEventListener("deviceready", onDeviceReady, false);
}

function onDeviceReady(){
  // Now safe to use the PhoneGap API
}
```

Then:

```
<body onload="onLoad()">
```

This will ensure the DOM is ready before the deviceready is called

Answer (score 0):

Best experience that I've had with PhoneGap based apps is using [FastClick](https://github.com/ftlabs/fastclick) library and initializing your app like this:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="vendor/fastclick/lib/fastclick.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">
    window.addEventListener('load', function() {
        FastClick.attach(document.getElementById('container'));

        document.addEventListener('deviceready', function () {
            // Initialize your app here
        });
    });
</script>
```

You could also take a look at this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1236040/1109883) for more details on document load event.

FastClick must be used for eliminating the 300ms delay between a physical tap and the firing of a click event on mobile browsers.