# Using "this" object inside click event handler

Tags: jquery, cordova, phonegap-build

I am writing PhoneGap application. I compile it using the PhoneGap Build web service. I have not included jQuery Mobile, though I have included jQuery in my project. In a pure web application I often use code like this:

```
<html>
    <body>
        <div class="button" id="button1">Hello</div>
        <script> 
            $(".button").click(function() {
                alert($(this).attr("id"));
            });
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

However, in PhoneGap, I find that when I reference any attribute of my `$(".button")` element via jQuery's `$(this)`, the value of the attribute is  `undefined`. What should I do?

Comment: If I reference anything by using $(this) the value is undefined.
example: alert($(this).attr("id"));  or alert($(this).html());

Comment: Yes, Jquery is included.  I am able to use JQuery's may features extensively throughout the page- just "$(this)" fails.

Comment: Strange. Did you use `jQuery(this)`?

Comment: @kmsdev if `$(".button")` does work, there should not be any problems with `$(this)`.

Comment: I know, that's why I wrote "strange". That piece of code should work as expected (if jQuery has been loaded)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The event was not firing because the document was not *ready*. For phonegap I needed to register the event inside of the deviceReady() method.  There is more about the event here:
[Phonegap deviceready vs document ready](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12864766/phonegap-deviceready-vs-document-ready)