# Setting body onload without using the <body> tag

Tags: javascript, onload

I am trying to a function to trigger once the body loads. I know that you can do this from the body tag, but I would prefer to do this from JS if this is possible.

For example: `document.getElementsByTagName('body').onload = someFunc();`

This does not work for me, but I think it shows what I essentially want to do.

**EDIT:**

I have tried the answers, what seems to be the issue is that it is calling the function before the elements it uses in the body tag are loaded, even if I put the script tags inside the body.
This is what it needs to do:

`var buttonElements = document.getElementsByClassName('button');`

And if I do:

`alert(buttonElements)`

It will pop up `0`, but when I create a variable in the console, it will successfully populate it with the elements.

Comment: You should try window.onload http://stackoverflow.com/questions/588040/window-onload-vs-document-onload

Comment: "someFunc" should be `someFunc`, no? And you can use shortcut form `document.body`, too.

Comment: The down votes are because the `""`?

Comment: Also the `body` has to exist before trying to access it : ).

Comment: possible duplicate of [Attach a body onload event with JS](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1235985/attach-a-body-onload-event-with-js)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

What you've got will almost work, but you have to import your JavaScript at the end of the `<body>` tag, and you have to index the first result:

```
document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0].onload = someFunc;
```

Answer (score 5):

Like so:

```
window.onload = someFunc;
```

If however, your function accepts arguemnts, you would need anonymous function like this:

```
window.onload = function(){
    someFunc(arg1, arg2);
}
```

BTW, other than fix that @Pointy mentioned for your code, you can also do:

```
document.body.onload = someFunc;
```

Answer (score 2):

Dont use quotes... `"someFunc"()` won't work if you try to run it anyways.

```
window.onload = someFunc;
```

Answer (score 2):

If you use jQuery:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    callMyFunction();
});
```