# Geocodezip code is not working with WordPress loop

Tags: php, wordpress, geocoding

I want to show map in each WordPress post. Location will be vary, address will get fetched from database. This code is generating the result, but not working properly.

1. Map Maker is missing.
2. Zoom option is not working or I can't see it visually.

This function need initialize() mentioned in body tag so I have customized my body tag as:

```
<body onload="initialize()">
```

Here is the script I am using:

```
    var geocoder;
    var map;
    var address ="<?php echo $address;?>";
    function initialize() {
    geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();
    var myOptions = {
    zoom: 16,
    center: new google.maps.LatLng(-33, 151),
    mapTypeControl: true,
    mapTypeControlOptions: {style: google.maps.MapTypeControlStyle.DROPDOWN_MENU},
    navigationControl: true,
    mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
    };
    map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map_canvas"), myOptions);
    if (geocoder) {
    geocoder.geocode( { 'address': address}, function(results, status) {
    if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {
      if (status != google.maps.GeocoderStatus.ZERO_RESULTS) {
      map.setCenter(results[0].geometry.location);

        var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow(
            { content: '<b>'+address+'</b>',
              size: new google.maps.Size(150,50)
            });

        var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
            position: results[0].geometry.location,
            map: map, 
            title:address
        }); 
        google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function() {
            infowindow.open(map,marker);
        });

      } else {
        alert("No results found");
       }
     } else {
      alert("Geocode was not successful for the following reason: " + status);
    }
     });
     }
     }
```

I am using Div which show result in WordPress post loop:

```
<div id="map_canvas" style="width:470px; height:358px"></div>
```

This code is working perfect while used in [HTML file](http://www.geocodezip.com/GMapsExampleV3b.html), because of my poor knowledge I am unable to figure out why it is not working when div is in loop

Answer (score 0):

You should use [`wp_enqueue_scripts`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/wp_enqueue_scripts), but the problem is passing the value `<?php echo $address;?>`. It can be solved with [`wp_localize_script`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_localize_script).

The following is a working example of shortcode, used as `[gmaps address="city, state, country"]` inside your content.

```
<?php
/* Plugin Name: My Gmaps */

add_shortcode( 'gmaps', 'gmaps_so_18671818' );

function gmaps_so_18671818( $atts ) 
{
    $address = isset( $atts['address'] ) ? $atts['address'] : '275-291 Bedford Ave, Brooklyn, NY 11211, USA';
    wp_register_script( 
        'gmaps',
        'https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?v=3.exp&sensor=false',
        array(),
        null,
        true
    );
    wp_enqueue_script( 
        'call-gmaps',
        plugin_dir_url( __FILE__ ) . '/call-gmaps.js',
        array( 'gmaps' ),
        null,
        true 
    );
    wp_localize_script( 
        'call-gmaps', 
        'my_vars',
        array( 'address' => $address ) 
    );
    return '<div id="map_canvas" style="width:470px; height:358px"></div>';
}
```

The file **`call-gmaps.js`** is located in the plugin folder. The first part of the script is from [this Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1236040/1287812), and takes care of the `onload` event. The address is being passed inside `my_vars.address`:

```
// https://stackoverflow.com/a/1236040/1287812
// Dean Edwards/Matthias Miller/John Resig
function init() {
    if (arguments.callee.done) return;
    // flag this function so we don't do the same thing twice
    arguments.callee.done = true;
    // kill the timer
    if (_timer) clearInterval(_timer);
    // do stuff
    initialize();
};

/* for Mozilla/Opera9 */
if (document.addEventListener) {
    document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", init, false);
}

/* for Internet Explorer */
/*@cc_on @*/
/*@if (@_win32)
    document.write("<script id=__ie_onload defer src=javascript:void(0)><\/script>");
    var script = document.getElementById("__ie_onload");
    script.onreadystatechange = function() {
        if (this.readyState == "complete") {
            init(); // call the onload handler
        }
    };
/*@end @*/

/* for Safari */
if (/WebKit/i.test(navigator.userAgent)) { // sniff
    var _timer = setInterval(function() {
        if (/loaded|complete/.test(document.readyState)) {
            init(); // call the onload handler
        }
    }, 10);
}

/* for other browsers */
window.onload = init;



var geocoder;
var map;
var address = my_vars.address; // <---- PASSED BY wp_localize_script
function initialize() {
    geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();
    var myOptions = {
        zoom: 16,
        center: new google.maps.LatLng(-33, 151),
        mapTypeControl: true,
        mapTypeControlOptions: {style: google.maps.MapTypeControlStyle.DROPDOWN_MENU},
        navigationControl: true,
        mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
    };
    map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map_canvas"), myOptions);
    if (geocoder) {
        geocoder.geocode( { 'address': address}, function(results, status) {
            if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {
                if (status != google.maps.GeocoderStatus.ZERO_RESULTS) {
                    map.setCenter(results[0].geometry.location);

                    var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow(
                    { content: '<b>'+address+'</b>',
                        size: new google.maps.Size(150,50)
                    });

                    var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                        position: results[0].geometry.location,
                        map: map, 
                        title:address
                    }); 
                    google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function() {
                        infowindow.open(map,marker);
                    });

                } else {
                    console.log("No results found");
                }
            } else {
                console.log("Geocode was not successful for the following reason: " + status);
            }
        });
    }
}
```

It is possible to adapt all this to work with a Custom Field to store the address and use `get_post_meta()` to localize the script.

Comment: Hey! Thanks for the help, but it is generating same result as my code is generating. And same issue/error as my previous code is generating.

I mean location marker is missing and Zoom functionality is not working.

Comment: Do you have a live link? I tested the code above and worked ok.

Comment: BTW! I converted "http://www.geocodezip.com/GMapsExampleV3b.html" this HTML format into PHP format and I found that Marker is missing and Zoom option is no more working. So I guess it is because of PHP format I am using... please guide me on that. Thanks :)

Comment: When I test the code and put a SO address this is [what shows up](http://cl.ly/image/2K3A1X0a0Y1W). Does your browser console dumps any error?

Comment: You are adding address manually, while I am fetching it from database. Which is different for each post. here is a link of one post "http://apotheekvinder.nl/?p=2828" try zooming map please

Comment: I am sorry Brasofilo, but I have to switch site to maintenance mode right now! any help will be surely appreciated. Thanks for what so ever you did!

Answer (score 0):

You know... it was my browser cache which was causing problem. I cleared cache and it is working.

Thanks for the help I really appreciate your efforts and apologize for wasting your valuable time.