# Trigger OnLoad Javascript in .Net on content page

Tags: javascript, html, asp.net

Issue: Load Javascript on load on a 'content page'.

I have some test Javascript code that I launch with

```
<body onload="javascript:SomeFunction()">
```

(Code specific is  `<body onload="GetMap(); ClickGeocode()">`)

However I now want to put the code into a .Net page which has a masterpage. What I do not want to do is to have the Javascript loading on the masterpage as that would mean it loads on every page when I want it only on one page.

I have tried on here and Google to find a solution but am not sure on the terminology! 
I have looked at [How do I call a JavaScript function on page load?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3842614/how-do-i-call-a-javascript-function-on-page-load?rq=1) as an example of research.

Code in full:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html>
<head>
    <title></title>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
        <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ecn.dev.virtualearth.net/mapcontrol/mapcontrol.ashx?v=6.3"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">

    var map = null;

    function GetMap() {
        map = new VEMap('myMap');
        map.LoadMap();

    }

    function ClickGeocode() {

        map.Geocode(document.getElementById('<%= txtQuery.ClientID %>').value, findCallback);
    }

    function findCallback(layer, findResults, placeResults, moreResults, error) {
        var s = '';
        if (placeResults) {
            for (var i = 0; i < placeResults.length; ++i) {
                s += 'Name: ' + placeResults[i].Name + '\n';
                s += 'LatLong: ' + placeResults[i].LatLong + '\n';
                s += 'MatchCode: ' + placeResults[i].MatchCode + '\n';
                s += 'MatchConfidence: ' + placeResults[i].MatchConfidence + '\n';
                s += '\n\n';
            }
        }
        else {
            // Code was an error! 
            // Do something else!
         //   console.log(error);
        }

    }
 </script>
   </head>
   <body onload="GetMap(); ClickGeocode()">

      <div id='myMap' style="position:relative; width:400px; height:400px;"></div>      

     <form runat="server"> 
       <asp:TextBox ID="txtQuery" runat="server" text="Postcode Here" />

       </form>
   </body>
</html>
```

Comment: You're example code does not show what you mention in your question, you only show a single page, not a Master page and a Content page.

Comment: This may be of some help : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1235985/attach-a-body-onload-event-with-js

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use proper events or call your code where required elements are already available.

Add the following to the bottom of the document (inside `<body>` of course):

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  myFunction();
</script>
```

Using events, possible in both `<head>` and `<body>`:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", myFunction, false);
</script>
```

Comment: Worth noting that IE8 and lower don't support the `DOMContentLoaded` event. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Reference/Events/DOMContentLoaded

Comment: That is, correct, of course. Alternatively, the "load" event can also be used, although it's fired later.

Comment: Okay so if i read it right I go to the content page and on the last content area I put <script type="text/javascript">
  myFunction();
</script> and then add <script type="text/javascript">
  document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", myFunction, false);
</script> to the content page in the header part or is that two ways to do it?

Comment: The Javascript ideally will fire last as I need to get the postcode first before I generate the map