# How do I run this function on page load?

Tags: javascript

I have to wrap my functions in a namespace. How do I run my function on page load in this format?

```
window.myFunction = { submitButton: function () {

document.getElementById('button').value='My text';

}
window.onload = submitButton;
};
```

If I write this without the namespace, it works fine

```
function submitButton() {     document.getElementById('button').value='My text'; }

window.onload = submitButton;
```

Comment: I think his question is about how to get to submitButton not onload which he already have in his question

Comment: Closer to a duplicate of: http://stackoverflow.com/q/1235985/1807040 also I think you meant. `window.init = window.myFunction.submitButton`

Comment: this piece of code is not formatted correctly. it does not execute like this because you are making an assignment  to `window.onload` within an object body!

Comment: Dominic you can assign function to onload. - thats what you should do actually.

Comment: yes but you can't assign it while you are initializing an object. that will not run. try to execute his first piece of code and you will see what I mean.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`myFunction` in your example is an object not a function and submitButton is a property of that object, to access it you'll do this:

```
window.onload = window.myFunction.submitButton;
```

**update**

Something like this will run multiple functions.

```
 window.onload = function(){
    for(var prop in window.myFunction) { 
      if(window.myFunction.hasOwnProperty(prop) && typeof window.myFunction[prop] === 'function') {
        window.myFunction[prop]();
      }
    }
 };
```

Comment: How can I run multiple functions in `window.onload`?

Comment: Run multiple function - what do you mean ?

Comment: Like if I had another object in my namespace in addition to `submitButton` and I wanted that to run when `window.onload`, as well.

Comment: check my answer i've update it.

Comment: Awesome, thanks again!