# add script to head that runs after the body has been loaded

Tags: javascript, html

How to add `myFunction()` in `head` that runs only after the `body` has been loaded. The reason I want to have it inside `head` is because that way I could put it in only one file instead of multiple.

Currently I have `<body onload="myFunction()"></body>` which works perfectly. But this needs to be added to multiple files.

Example

```html
<head>
  <style>
    .codetext {
      font-family: monospace;
    }
  </style>

  <script>
    myFunction = function () {
      let links = document.querySelectorAll("a");
      links.forEach(elem => elem.classList.add("codetext"));
    }
 document.body.onload("myFunction"); <!--Doesn't Work-->
  </script>
</head>

<body>
  <a href="">Click Here</a>
</body>
```

Comment: This question may already have been answered here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/799981/document-ready-equivalent-without-jquery

Comment: Why is `body.onload` used instead of `window.onload`? `<script>onload = _ => document.querySelectorAll("a").forEach(elem => elem.classList.add("codetext"))</script>`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use global [`load`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/GlobalEventHandlers/onload) event

```
<script>
  onload = _ => 
    document.querySelectorAll("a").forEach(elem => elem.classList.add("codetext"))
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `document.body.onload = handler`. See [this answer for more details](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1236040/9325419).

```html
<head>
  <style>
    .codetext {
      font-family: monospace;
    }
  </style>

  <script>
    document.body.onload = () => {
      const links = document.querySelectorAll('a');
      links.forEach(elem => elem.classList.add('codetext'));
    }
  </script>
</head>

<body>
  <a href="">Click Here</a>
</body>
```

Or you can use `window.onload = handler`.

Answer (score 1):

You can use

```
 document.querySelector('body').onload
```

```html
<head>
  <style>
    .codetext {
      font-family: monospace;
    }
  </style>

  <script>
    document.querySelector('body').onload= function myFunction() {
      let links = document.querySelectorAll("a");
      links.forEach(elem => elem.classList.add("codetext"));
    }
 //document.body.onload("myFunction"); <!--Doesn't Work-->
  </script>
</head>

<body>
  <a href="">Click Here</a>
</body>
```

Answer (score 1):

> TypeError: document.body.onload is not a function

you need to assign your function to `onload` : `document.body.onload = myFunction;`

```html
<head>
  <style>
    .codetext {
      font-family: monospace;
      color: red;
    }
  </style>

  <script>
    myFunction = function() {
      let links = document.querySelectorAll("a");
      links.forEach(elem => elem.classList.add("codetext"));
    }
    document.body.onload = myFunction;
  </script>
</head>

<body>
  <a href="">Click Here</a>
</body>
```

Comment: not sure, i'm using firefox and i'm not getting the error

Answer (score 0):

Use

```
document.body.addEventListener("load",functionToAssingn)
```

to add onLoad event:

```html
<head>
  <style>
    .codetext {
      font-family: monospace;
    }
  </style>

  <script>document.body.addEventListener("load",myFunction)
    myFunction = function () {
      let links = document.querySelectorAll("a");
      links.forEach(elem => elem.classList.add("codetext"));
    }
  </script>
</head>

<body>
  <a href="">Click Here</a>
</body>
```